# Using jQuery AJAX calls with the DigitalOcean API

Tags: jquery, api, digital-ocean

I am trying to use jQuery to call the DigitalOcean API and return user account info but my current code does not work.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'get',
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer b7d03a6947b217efb6f3ec3bd3504582'); // 'b7d03a6947b217efb6f3ec3bd3504582' is the default API key given in the docs, I used my normal one in my actual code.
  },
  success: function(result) {
        console.log("It worked!");
  }
});
```

I am following the documentation [here](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#get-user-information), and I am running an HTTP server using the [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) Node package.

Comment: In the console of your browser, are there any warnings or other log messages?

Comment: Your sample code works for me. I tried with both a token generated here https://cloud.digitalocean.com/settings/api/tokens and a token generated via an OAuth application.